# find the crossed kink when checking gradient

Tags: deep-learning, caffe

I am dealing with a numerical problem in gradient check.

I am not sure if there is a "crossed kink" as describe in cs231n (http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-3/#gradcheck).

In the description from cs231n, one way to check if there is a crossed kink is to use max function

> Note that it is possible to know if a kink was crossed in the evaluation of the loss. This can be done by keeping track of the identities of all “winners” in a function of form max(x,y); That is, was x or y higher during the forward pass. If the identity of at least one winner changes when evaluating f(x+h) and then f(x−h), then a kink was crossed and the numerical gradient will not be exact

What is the "identities"?

And what is "x" or "y" in gradient check?

Can someone help me understand that by providing a concrete example?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question,
"Identities" here would mean keeping track of (identity of) which of x or y were "winner" when evaluating max(x,y).

Now to explain the second part:

By keeping the track of identity,
"If the identity of at least one winner changes ..." => Meaning, after evaluating the gradient, if the "winner" variable changes, we would know that "the kink was crossed".

Example:
Suppose we have max(0, x=-0.1). The "winner" during forward-pass would be '0'.
Now, when evaluating f(x+h) (suppose h=0.2)

f(x+h) = max(0, -0.1+0.2) = 0.1

Note that, the "winner" here changed while evaluating gradient (from 0 previously to "x+h" now).

Hence we would know that the kink was crossed.